# overflow not working -- document height growing

Tags: html, css

I am confused as to why this small bit of html + css makes my $(document).height() huge.  It seems the overflow container isn't completely working.  Here is a jsbin showing the errant behavior:  http://jsbin.com/omokin/1

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#container {overflow:auto;height:500px;width:300px;}
#big {height:90000px;background-color: pink;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="big">
</div>
<div style='visibility:hidden; position:absolute;'>x</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have put a div with a `position:absolute` in the container under the big div. You'll notice when you scroll down to the bottom of the page in your example the hidden div with x is there.

http://jsbin.com/omokin/6/

If you change the order slightly, then the `position:absolute` won't push the whole page down.

```
<div id="container">
  <div style='visibility:hidden; position:absolute;'>x</div>
<div id="big">
</div>
</div>
```

In other words you can't use an absolute position in the context you're using it. You'll need to either remove the absolute positioning or move that div above the big div.

Comment: Two years later, this just helped me fix a bug that's been plaguing me for 6 months. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).height()` will be huge as you have a longer height of `div#big (#big {height:90000px})`.

As per the .height function, its takes the height of the document which is really huge.

You can have a look into this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Answer (score 0):

its correct the `#big` `height:90000px` is in `#container height:500px` and you set `#container` `overflow:auto`. If you don't want the `scroll` make `overflow` auto to `hidden`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/omokin/8/edit

You want to set the hidden element's top property to 0 because if you look at the top property is being pushed by the big element.

Comment: Rather than setting it with a value of `top:0` wouldn't it make mroe sense to just move the div to the top?

Comment: Yeah, would make more sense to restructure, that's why I upvoted your answer! Wasn't sure if he laid it out that way for a reason or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `position: relative` on the `#container` div. If you don't do that and your markup has structure you described, that absolutely positioned div will ignore any overflow property effects between itself and its containing block (which is root element in this case, because there are no positioned parents).